# Cocos2dx is frozen after AdColony video playing in iPhone

Tags: ios

I have integrated AdColony Video Ad to the cocos2d-x game in iPhone.
cocos2d-x version is cocos2d-x v3.3.4

The problem is that the game is frozen after playing AdColony video.

My game is portrait mode, but AdColony supports only landscape mode for iPhone.
After playing AdColony video, it goes back to the game screen, but frozen, and showing the following console logs.

> OpenGL error 0x0506 in
>   /Project/Working/BomberCode/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCRenderer.cpp
>   saveRenderState 144
>
> OpenGL error 0x0506 in
>   /Project/Working/BomberCode/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCTextureAtlas.cpp
>   drawNumberOfQuads 691
>
> OpenGL error 0x0506 in
>   /Project/Working/BomberCode/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCTextureAtlas.cpp
>   drawNumberOfQuads 691
>
> OpenGL error 0x0506 in
>   /Project/Working/BomberCode/cocos2d/cocos/renderer/CCRenderer.cpp
>   restoreRenderState 170
>
> OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCEAGLView swapBuffers] 324

I have paused OpenGL before playing adColony and then, resumed after playing with the following code, but same issue is appeared.

```
Director::getInstance()->pause();
Director::getInstance()->stopAnimation();

Director::getInstance()->resume();
Director::getInstance()->startAnimation();
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried hiding your main UIWindow while AdColony is in control of your game?

Answer (score 0):

It seems AdColony conflicts with cocos2d-x when using opengl, you can use a new window for AdColony. There is a completely plugin for AdColony for cocos2d-x, and I find this solution in their class:

https://github.com/glossom-dev/AdColony_plugin_for_cocos2dx/blob/master/adcolony/proj.ios/PluginAdColony/AdsAdColony.mm